# Can we use students' class homework solution for research purpose?

Tags: ethics, data, homework, legal-issues, privacy

A colleague of mine would like to compare 25+ different Java implementations of the same homework. Is it OK (ethically/legally in the US) to share my students' class homework solutions with him for his research purposes?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to run this by your Institutional Review Board (IRB), as you would any time you use data from human subjects for research.

From what you describe, it has a good chance of qualifying for an [IRB exemption](http://www.hhs.gov/ohrp/humansubjects/guidance/45cfr46.html) under one of these categories (if identifying information is removed before giving the data to the researcher):

- It is using existing data
- the data comes from normal educational practices

but even then, **the IRB needs to be the one to make that determination**.

Comment: What is an IRB?

Comment: @gerrit US academic institutions often (always?) has an [Institutional Review Board (IRB)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutional_review_board) (or some committees that act as such, e.g. here at MIT the  [Committee on the Use of Humans as Experimental Subjects (COUHES)](https://couhes.mit.edu/) was established to act as the Institutional Review Board (IRB)), which is a committee that has been formally designated to approve, monitor, and review biomedical and behavioral research involving humans. I actually went through it recently for some research on MOOC data.

Comment: Assuming you had signed consent letters from the students, would you still require such approval?

Comment: @Raphael you still have to get everything approved by the IRB. The investigator has a conflict of interest here, the IRB is necessary as a third party oversight body.

Comment: note that many IRBs have IRB exception applications that are often very short 1-2 pgs. A full IRB request is usually in excess of 20 pgs of forms and essays. The two most important factors that are relevant in your case is (1) do you have the student's consent and (2) is there anyway that the data as stored could even possibly be traced back to the student's identity. If your answers are 1-yes and 2-no you will most certainly get an exemption.

Comment: @MHH  actually for exempt research, explicit consent is often *not* required (or, implied consent is sufficient). Consult your IRB for details.

Comment: 'Institutional Review Board' is a US term but I would expect any university or research institution to have an equivalent body that should be approached for approval. The key point is that it is not up to the researcher themselves to decide on the ethics of their own research.

Answer (score 5):

Franck doesn't say where he is.  What ff524 says is true in the US.  Any research with human subjects must be approved by an appropriate review process beforehand.

One horror story (allegedly true) goes like this.  A graduate student in music history spent her summer touring through Appalachia, convincing people to let her record them singing traditional songs.  But that research had to be thrown out, because of the advance approval process she hadn't known was required.

Comment: Thanks, interesting. I'm in the US. What advance approval process did she need? IRB approval?

Comment: What the approval process is called may depend on your institution.  I believe ours was called something about "Human Subjects".  There was another committee to deal with "Research using live animals".

Comment: Its more than just the US, many, if not all, large academic institutes have IRB in order to comply to ethical issues and requirements of international journals regarding human subjects

Comment: -1 This seems to be an anecdote rather than an answer to the question